# Summarise at each level and attach that to the summary in the next level R's tidyverse

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

My desired output is to add `DATA2` to `DATA3` while preserving `DATA3` number of rows.

Is it possible to pipe these two into each other such that first we compute `n()` at `EL` level and then under EL further compute `n()` at `EL and Black` levels right under it?

In other words, is it possible for the results of `n()` to shown in the lower levels?

```
library(tidyverse)

DATA <- structure(list(EL = c("Former", "Current", "Former", "Current", 
"Former", "Former", "Current", "Current", "Current", "Current"
), Black = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
"No", "No"), Language = c("Spanish", "Spanish", "English", "Vietnamese", 
"Chinese", "Vietnamese", "Spanish", "Amharic", "Romanian", "English"
)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 35L, 38L, 50L, 54L, 61L, 71L
), class = "data.frame")


DATA2 <- DATA %>% group_by(EL) %>% 
  mutate(n_EL_Type = n())


DATA3 <- DATA %>% group_by(EL, Black, Language) %>% 
  summarise(Number = n()) %>% 
  mutate(Total = sum(Number), Percentage = paste0(round(Number/Total*100,2),"%")
  ) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Percentage),Language,EL) %>%
  filter(Language %in% c("Spanish","Amharic"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DATA |>
  mutate(n_EL_Type = n(), .by = EL) |>
  add_count(EL, Black, Language) |>
  mutate(Total = sum(n), Percentage = scales::percent(Total / sum(Total)), .by = c(EL, Black)) |>
  arrange(desc(Percentage),Language,EL) |> 
  filter(Language %in% c("Spanish","Amharic"))

       EL Black Language n_EL_Type n Total Percentage
1 Current   Yes  Amharic         6 1     2        50%
2 Current   Yes  Spanish         6 1     2        50%
3 Current    No  Spanish         6 1     4        25%
4  Former    No  Spanish         4 1     4        25%
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply looking for:

```
library(tidyverse)

DATA %>% group_by(EL) %>% 
  mutate(n_EL_Type = n()) %>%
  group_by(EL, Black, Language) %>% 
  summarise(n_EL_Type = n_EL_Type,
            Number = n()) %>% 
  mutate(Total = sum(Number),
         Percentage = paste0(round(Number/Total*100,2),"%")
  ) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Percentage),Language,EL) %>%
  filter(Language %in% c("Spanish","Amharic"))

# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Groups:   EL, Black [3]
  EL      Black Language n_EL_Type Number Total Percentage
  <chr>   <chr> <chr>        <int>  <int> <int> <chr>     
1 Current Yes   Amharic          6      1     2 50%       
2 Current Yes   Spanish          6      1     2 50%       
3 Current No    Spanish          6      1     4 25%       
4 Former  No    Spanish          4      1     4 25%
```

Comment: Yes, I used the same method, but when the number of rows in `DATA2` and `DATA3` are not the same, using `distinct()` at the end is necessary to arrive at the desired output.